# GridFs read PDF

Tags: pymongo

I am trying to build a financial dashboard with Flask and pymongo. The starting point is a flask form which saves data in a MongoDB database. One of the fields in the form is a FileField (wtforms) which allows the upload of a PDF, which is then stored in MongoDB with GridFS.
Now I manage to save the pdf and I can see the resulting entries within the .files and .chunks collections. Now I would like to build a function that retrieves the PDFs and analyses them with some basic NLP, however I struggle with the getting meaningful data.

When I do:

```
storage = gridfs.GridFS(db, collection)
data = storage.get('some id')
a = data.read()
```

The result is a binary file. If I continue with:

```
with open(data, 'rb') as f:
   b = f.read()
```

The result is "ValueError: embedded null byte or sometimes an empty "byte string".

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the above, I found a solution for myself that consists in 2 separate functions:

(1) Upon upload of the form and before uploading the files to MongoDB, I apply a function based on pdfminer that extracts the string content of the PDF and tranform it into a list of sentences using NLTK. I will then store this list in the .files via the `storage.put(file, sent_list = sent_list) #sent_list being the variable name of the list of sentences.`
Whenever I wish to run NLP operations on the file, I will just call the "sent_list" variable from mongodb.

(2) If I wish to display the stored pdf in its original content however, I included the following function as a separate route.

```
storage = GridFS(db, collection)
data = storage.get_last_version(filename)
response = make_response(data.read())
extension = data.filename.split('.')[-1]
response.headers['Content-Type'] = f'application/{extension}'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename={data.filename}'
return response
```

(2) will open a new tab in my flask app showing the .pdf file in its original format.

I hope this helps anyone coming across a similar problem in the future.